# 401 Unauthorized: [Package name] error during npm install from azure DevOps feed

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I'm using AzureDevop artifacts for npm feeds. When I try to do `npm install` I'm getting `401 Unauthorized` exception.

Any idea what is causing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. My authorization token expired. Just needed to go to feed/connect-to-feed and regenerate token for npm and put it into .npmrc file.

Answer (score 2):

Your authorization token has probably expired. Go to you .npmrc file and look for the following section to confirm expiration date of token, as highlighted:
[image]

To update it, Login to azure DevOps:

1. Click on Artifacts
2. Select connect to feed
   [image]
3. Select npm
4. Under project setup select other then
   [image]
5. Click on generate npm credentials
6. Copy the credentials
7. Paste replace the expired token in .npmrc file

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your token is expired.

1. Go to Azure Devops
2. From this menu [image] at the top right corner choose `Personal access tokens`
3. Find the expired token which matches your problem e.g. has `Packaging (Read)` access to the failing url in 401 error message.
4. Select the token and Regenerate.
5. go back to your console and run `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -F`

---

If it's your first time you have to create a new token with sufficent access to packaging and run `npm install -g vsts-npm-auth` in your console before running `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -F` (I always put that `-F` there even if it's not needed).

---

If you're still having problem I suggest you find the detailed instructions in the Azure Devops:

1. Go to Artifacts
2. Connect to feed
3. npm
4. click on `Having issues? See the instructions for using a Personal Access Token to authenticate.` and read the whole instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth pointing out that **even if your token is clearly NOT expired**, still try to renew it and see what happens. This solved my problem (`yarn install` with 401 Unauthorized)